# command line dictionary program supporting MDX files on Ubuntu

Tags: gratis, command-line, dictionary

Is there any free command line dictionary program on Ubuntu that supports `.mdx` [MDict dictionary](https://www.mdict.cn/wp/?lang=en) files?